# Why is OR || operator not working for this if statement?

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, if-statement

I made a grid in Unity that can read data from my game objects (tetris blocks in this case) on it and translate their type and rotation into coded strings saved in a .txt file. I use these .txt files to later instantiate the blocks when loading a level.

So for example, an L block with a rotation of z of 0 is written as "L0", a T block with 90 degrees rotation is saved as "T1", a square with 180 degrees is saved as "S2", etc...

In some cases, since sprites are instantiated from their center, I need to give them with a positional offset to align them with the grid. I found the outliers and wrote this method down:

```
if (name != "CS" || name != "L" || name != "E" || name != "Z")
{
   currentBlock.transform.position = new Vector3(currentBlock.transform.position.x - blockParams.posOffset.y, currentBlock.transform.position.y - blockParams.posOffset.x, 0);
}
else
{
   currentBlock.transform.position = new Vector3(currentBlock.transform.position.x + blockParams.posOffset.y, currentBlock.transform.position.y - blockParams.posOffset.x, 0);
}
```

Disregard the code inside the loop, it works. I just need another formula for the 4 mentioned in the if check at the top (CS, L, E and Z), hence the if-else.

Now my actual question is about that if check. As written here, they do not work for some reason. But if I do them individually, such as this:

```
if (name != "CS")
{
   currentBlock.transform.position = new Vector3(currentBlock.transform.position.x - blockParams.posOffset.y, currentBlock.transform.position.y - blockParams.posOffset.x, 0);
}
else
{
   currentBlock.transform.position = new Vector3(currentBlock.transform.position.x + blockParams.posOffset.y, currentBlock.transform.position.y - blockParams.posOffset.x, 0);
}
```

It works fine! I believe my issue is with the || operator. Does it not work with strings? I'd really appreciate a solution that doesn't make me go through making four if loops in the middle of my function...

Comment: name != "CS" || name != "L" is true is you pass there "CS" or "L" as well.. maybe you would like to use &&?

Comment: Oh my god, you're right... Well, that's embarassing. I guess I tunnel visionned.

Answer (score 2):

The two blocks of code you provided are logically very different.

As long the name is not `CS` or if it's not `E` for example, this code will be run.

```cs
if (name != "CS" || name != "L" || name != "E" || name != "Z")
```

If you want to check that the name is not **any of those names**, then you want to replace the `||` with `&&`.

```cs
if (name != "CS" && name != "L" && name != "E" && name != "Z")
```

Only if the name **is any** of those "CS", "L", "E", "Z", the `else` statement will be executed.

---

##### Explanation

```cs
if (name != "CS") // true if name is L, E, Z
{
   currentBlock.transform.position = new Vector3(currentBlock.transform.position.x - blockParams.posOffset.y, currentBlock.transform.position.y - blockParams.posOffset.x, 0);
}
else // executed if the name is CS
{
   currentBlock.transform.position = new Vector3(currentBlock.transform.position.x + blockParams.posOffset.y, currentBlock.transform.position.y - blockParams.posOffset.x, 0);
}
```

The following might not work as you'd expect it to.
You're basically saying:

> "It's okay if the name is not CS, it's okay if the name is not L, it's okay if the name is not E, it's okay if the name is not Z", which will work for any of the letters.

```cs
// true if the name is L, CS, E, Z
if (name != "CS" || name != "L" || name != "E" || name != "Z")
{
   currentBlock.transform.position = new Vector3(currentBlock.transform.position.x - blockParams.posOffset.y, currentBlock.transform.position.y - blockParams.posOffset.x, 0);
}
else // never executed for CS, L, E, Z
{
   currentBlock.transform.position = new Vector3(currentBlock.transform.position.x + blockParams.posOffset.y, currentBlock.transform.position.y - blockParams.posOffset.x, 0);
}
```

Instead of writing confusing logic that prioritizes negative statements:

```cs
if (name != "CS") { /* ...do A */ }
else { /* ...do B */ }
```

just write

```cs
if (name == "CS") { /* ...do B */ }
else { /* ...do A */ }
```

that will make your code easier to read, and more importantly to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check in multiple string then you can create a extension method like this.

```
public static bool In<T>(this T source, IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    return items.Contains(source);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
var list = new List<string>() {"CS" ,"L" ,"E" ,"Z" };
if(name.In(list))
{
    //your code
}
else
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: and why not simply rather stick to the existing and therefore more common `if(list.Contains(name))` ...?

Comment: It's a more elegant way to deal with and in future it may be possible that the if statement needed some type of list to check or validate in that case it will be helpful.